# Logging in Eco.MVC.EcoController

Tags: mdriven

In my MDriven MVC application I'm logging Trace messages into a log file. It seems that the class Eco.MVC.EcoController uses the Trace to log following events:

```
EcoController.EnsureEcoSpace: HomeController
EcoController.EnsureEcoSpace: CreateEcoSpace
EcoController.ReleaseEcoSpace: Disposing EcoSpace
OnResultExecuted (EcoController out of scope).
```

Is it possible to switch this logging off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops - no they were not optional. Checking in fix for this now. 
They will be default off and turned on with:

```
EcoTraceCategories.WebDebugPrint = true;
```