# Stop EcoSpace from writing PM events to debug output?

Tags: logging, mdriven

In our WinForms app and our ASP.NET app using MDriven FW 7, I notice that the EcoSpace writes all PM events to the debug output. I think this slows it down and would like to disable it.

How do I control this feature?

Update:
I now noticed that the source of the messages is not MDriven's PM, but the FIrebird .NET client. Consequently, this question is moot.

Comment: What kind of output do you see?
Is the MVC trace that was talked about in this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063301/logging-in-eco-mvc-ecocontroller

Comment: Don't think so. I see PM messages with SQL and param values.

Comment: Hmm - db is SqlServer or MySql or other?

Comment: Firebird, from your other PM:s package, built here.

Comment: But what *should* control this debug output?

Answer (score 0):

Any log the PMMapper writes in normal runtime should adhere to the EcoLogSwitches.LogSql switch. Do you have it turned on?

Comment: Where? Web.config/app.config? Designer property? Code?

Comment: A search for `LogSql` in the entire solution reveals that it's being set only in places that are not executed, and specifically are not executed at start-up. Clarified that I know I see this in the ASP.NET app, not so sure about the WinForms app.